# Ввод строк равных их количеству

Tags: java

Всем привет, я новичок в олимпиадах.
При решении задачи появилось такое условие:
число N – количество предметов. В следующих N строках даны массы предметов
как сделать такое на java? Можно ли сделать это с помощью Scanner?

Comment: вы можете ввести 1 строку? А потом запустить этот ввод одной строки в цикле?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = scanner.nextInt();
int[] mass = new int[n];

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    mass[i] = scanner.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: Заодно стоит показать, как mass сделать списком или массивом - скорее всего, это понадобится.